# How to consume different response bodies based on the status code using Retrofit?

Tags: android, api, rest, retrofit2

My Android app that uses Retrofit for REST calls needs to consume different response types for the same endpoint call, depending on the response code. For example:

- If I send a request to `GET /api/user/1` and the HTTP status code is `200` then I should get a response body like this:

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30
}
```

- But if I send a request to `GET /api/user/1` and the HTTP status code is `404` then I should get a response body like this:

```json
{
    "errorCode": "UserNotFound"
}
```

- But if I send a request to `GET /api/user/1` and the HTTP status code is `429` then I should get a response body like this:

```json
{
    "maxRequestsPerHour": 60,
    "requestsRemaining": 0,
    "newRequestAvailableAt": "2020-02-08T09:30:26Z"
}
```

I found some people online suggesting to create a Retrofit adapter to deserialize a successful response (between 0 to 200 range) and an error for everything else, like this:

```java
public interface ApiService {
  @GET("users/{userId}")
  Call<NetworkResponse<User, Error>> getUser(@Path("userId") String userId);
}
```

And this could work if I had only two types of possible response, a `User` response and an `Error` response, but the API that I'm trying to consume has multiple response bodies for the same endpoint, depending on the status code.

In the example above I showed 3 possible responses, but some endpoints have 5 different response types (with different fields), depending if the response is 200, 404, 409, 500, etc... I don't want to create an adapter on Retrofit to handle each possible response like this:

```java
public interface ApiService {
  @GET("users/{userId}")
  Call<NetworkResponse<User, ErrorNotFound, ErrorTooManyRequest, ServerError, WhateverError>> getUser(@Path("userId") String userId);
}
```

It doesn't look good, in my opinion.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a more elegant way to handle multiple (more than 2) response types to the same endpoint, depending on the status code of the response?
2. What are your thoughts on this REST API design approach? I have seen REST APIs before that return basically two response types, when request is successful and when the request fails for some reason, but the response when the request fails has always the same format (same number of fields), but this is the first time I see a REST API with multiple response formats for error, with completely different fields for each type of error.

Comment: `What are your thoughts on this REST API design approach?` this feels like you're asking for opinion, so i'd remove this part. this api seems quite horrible, what you could end up doing is creating one response object with all of these as variables inside of it - name, age, errorCode,maxRequestsPerHour and wrap your retrofit with Response<ClassWithAllVariables>, then you get access to the status code, based on that you could assume which values could be used, but all of this is messy

Comment: Agree with above comment . Anyway for error case you can check for `response.errorBody()` it will have this Json i guess . But since your Error holds an Object you have to create A Wrapper to move it across classes . Once that will have a a Generic type for respose and a Type for Error .